# protect asp.net web api 2 project with identity server 4

Tags: jwt, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver4, owin, identityserver3

I have an asp.net web api 2 project with .Net framework 4.8 and a centralized Identity Server 4 project. I want to validate jwt/access token generated from IS4 in my web api 2 project. I can understand its a duplicate question but somehow I am unable to find any suitable help and I am not sure what's missing. I have used `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` for token validation in web api project.

Startup.cs

```
using IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplicationApiNew.Startup))]

namespace WebApplicationApiNew
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44373",
                RequiredScopes = new[] { "api1" },
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Calling this API with a valid JWT bearer token still gives 401:

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public String GetName1()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
                if (identity != null)
                {
                    IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
                }
                return "Valid";
            }
            else
            {
                return "Invalid";
            }
        }
```

Error details:

```
2021-07-24 20:41:25.4133|DEBUG|Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware|Authentication failed
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidAudienceException: IDX10214: Audience validation failed. Audiences: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'. Did not match: validationParameters.ValidAudience: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]' or validationParameters.ValidAudiences: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Validators.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateAudience(IEnumerable`1 audiences, JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateTokenPayload(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat.Unprotect(String protectedText)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationHandler.<AuthenticateCoreAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to my problem. IS3 requires `aud` claim (with `/resources` in url) to be present in jwt/access token in order to validate the token. But on the other side IS4 has stopped emitting the `aud` claim by default. So we need to explicitly set IS4 server to emit `aud` claim to support legacy/old access token validation with `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation`.

```
            services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                ...
                options.EmitStaticAudienceClaim = true; // <- for older access token validation
            })
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryPersistedGrants()
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetIdentityResources())
                ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows:

```
IDX10214: Audience validation failed
```

If your JWT token contains an "aud" claim, the authentication middleware
is attempting to validate the audience claim, but there is no audience specified in your options. Can you try one of the following:

1. Set an audience in the options:

   Audience = "[your audience]"
2. Disable audience validation in the options:

   TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;

Refer to the identity server documentation for more details:

```
https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/apis.html
```